# Handle SIGTERM in Google Cloud Functions 2 gen

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

Recently I discovered that Cloud Run service allows you to handle SIGTERM signal when terminating container instance as shown in [this](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/samples/cloudrun-sigterm-handler) example. This feature is quite useful. Since second generation of cloud functions is powered by Cloud Run I wonder is it possible to do the same thing with it?

I tried this python code snippet with no luck, of course. Is it possible to handle this signal in some other way?

```
import functions_framework
import signal
import sys

def shutdown_handler(signal: int, frame) -> None:
    """Gracefully shutdown app."""
    print("Exiting process.", flush=True)
    sys.exit(0)


signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, shutdown_handler)

@functions_framework.http
def main(request):
    print("Hi!")
    return 'OK'
```

Comment: What do you mean by  "no luck"? Did you wait 15 minutes?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, I expect to see "Exiting process" message in the logs, but nothing happens.